# Put some reactions to the message

Tags: telegram, telethon

recently I wanted to write a script for my userbot that will put reactions to messages of certain users, but I came across a question how to put 3 different reactions from the list?
I have telegram premium, but I can only get one reaction from the list.
My code:

```py
@loader.watcher("only_messages")
async def watcher(self, message: Message):
    if not self.config["reaction_active"]:
        return
    reactions = self.config["reactions"]
    reactions_chance = self.config["reactions_chance"]

    for reaction in reactions:
        userid, chatid, *emoji_list = reaction.split("|")
        if userid == "all" and chatid == "global":
            return
        if (
            (str(message.sender_id) == userid or userid == "all")
            and (str(utils.get_chat_id(message)) == chatid or chatid == "global")
            and not (userid == "all" and self.config["ignore_self"] and message.out)
        ):
            if not await self._reactions_chance(reactions_chance, message):
                return
            if utils.get_chat_id(message) in self.config["shuffle_reactions"]:
                emoji_list = random.sample(emoji_list, len(emoji_list))
            await self._delay(chatid, userid)

            for emoji_reaction in emoji_list:
                if await self._react_message(message, emoji_reaction, chatid):
                    return
```

I tried it this way:

```py
for emoji_reaction in emoji_list:
    for _ in range(3):  # Изменено на 3 реакции
        if await self._react_message(message, emoji_reaction, chatid):
            return
```

But this did not lead to anything and the script still sets 1 reaction